# R/GIS: bulk processing, distance and elevation calcuation

Tags: r, gis

I have a dataframe `df` with three variable: `city`, `state` and `country`. I want to calculate 3 things

1. Calculate the latitude/longitude for each row.
2. Calculate the distance of each city from an arbitrary point, say country capital
3. Calculate the elevation of each point from the lat/long.

I can use the [dismo](http://www.oga-lab.net/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=dismo%3ageocode) package for 1, but can't figure out a way to "bulk process" from `df`, instead of copying and pasting the city, state and country names directly into the `geocode(c())` code. As for 2 and 3, I am stumped completely. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT NOTE: To other readers of this post... I appreciate the help from both Paul and Spacedman. The system won't allow me to mark more than one response as correct. I gave Paul the thumbs up because he responded before Spaceman. Please read what both of them have taken the time to write up. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll share my thoughts on each of the points:

For 1. you can use `paste` to create an input vector for geocode:

```
df$geocode_string = with(df, paste(city, state, country, sep = ", "))
coords_latlong = geocode(df$geocode_string)
```

In regard to point number 2, after converting `df` to one the classes provided by the `sp` package (`SpatialPointsDataFrame`, look at the `coordinates` function from `sp`), you can use spDistsN1 to find the distance of all the points to one other point.

The final is a bit more tricky, to find the height you need a DEM (digital elevation model). Maybe there is a more easy way along the lines of `geocode` which I am not aware of.

Comment: good to hear that you found this answer useful. If you think I gave the corrct answer, you could mark it as the correct answer. You could also wait and see for more answers, which might answer your third point.

Comment: Done and done. I added an edit to the original post to let other readers know I was helped by both you and Spacedman, but I couldn't mark both as correct. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the geonames.org service to query a location on either SRTM or ASTER elevation databases:

http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html

and you might even be able to use my geonames package:

https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/geonames/

to make life easier.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. If I understand it correctly, geonames data is not "census complete" in that it lists all locations in a country. Not much use in that case.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you use it for geocoding, but once you've got the lat-long you can use the elevation API to get number 3 on your list.

Comment: Nice straightforward way of getting information from the aster and srtm dem. Thanks!

Comment: Ah... I get it now. This is nice. Thanks, Spacedman. Just so that I understand it, when I run, for example, GNsrtm3(lat, lng), it should give me the height in mts, right? I tried GNsrtm3(27.988257, 86.925145) for Mt. Everest, and it's giving me -32768 (which I understand is a common error). Is there any simply way of getting a "real max elevation" to the lat/lng I type in?

Comment: That's exactly how it should work, but if there's errors in NASA's SRTM data and they are duplicated on geonames then there's no way I can fix them. You could also try the GNgtopo30 which gets elevation from another source. I forget which is meant to be better/more complete/more reliable but GNgtopo30 does at least know Everest is over 8000m. I suspect there's one dead pixel in the SRTM data that happens to be on Everest, since locations close to that point you gave are valid. These things are approximate - read up on them.